# arduino project for c programming language

Tags: programming, arduino-mega, c

i am a student from 2nd semester BCA (Bachelor in Computer Application). My group need some project for presentation from c programming language so i thought of using #ARDUINO project for our presentation . i really don't have any idea in this project so any ideas, answer, guides will be helpful to us.

Comment: Great idea - choose something you know nothing about and then beg others for help.  At least start with having a clue what you want to achieve, then we may be able to help you achieve it. Until then you're on your own.

Comment: I must say. Kind of a silly question. It indicates you've done virtually no reasearch on your own. Kind of like saying, I have a pencil and paper. I need some guidance as to what types of marks I can make on the paper with the pencil. :) Here's something that may give you some insight: see the latter 3 links that I posted in my answer here: http://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/16413/how-to-change-variable-when-a-button-connected-to-pin-2-is-pressed.

Answer (score 2):

Good luck with this! Arduino is awesome. I really enjoy using it. You may find this at least a little insightful: http://www.electricrcaircraftguy.com/2014/01/the-power-of-arduino.html.

Arduino is a small computer. It can do essentially whatever you want it to do: drive robots, fly airplanes, control motors, turn on or off TVs, get on the internet, make a home alarm, buzz a speaker, make a touch lamp, fade LEDs, play music (even with *no* music chip; just using a skillfully-written library), control HollyWood action cameras, talk to your smartphone, read your heartbeat, make a bike speedometer or odometer, read a GPS receiver, etc. Cool stuff!

Answer (score 0):

I am not going to list example-projects as the possibilities with an arduino are endless. If you are looking for inspiration: take a look at websites like www.instructables.com and www.hackaday.io. Those are websites with mostly starter arduino projects that contain step-by-step guides on how they are created. I would suggest that you browse through those projects and look for something that peaks your interest and then think of your own similar project. You should however think of a project with a certain complexity as it is for your bachelor's. Most projects on instrucables lack the challenge. For getting parts: take a look at ebay. Ebay has some webshops that sell arduino's and arduino extension modules really cheap.
Good luck

Comment: Instructables is the worst site. Please rethink your answer.

Comment: I do agree with you that instructables is not a website for someone looking for a project with a challenge of some sort. Instructables contains examples of easy to follow and replicatable projects. It also has tutorials like "how to upload blink to an arduino" or "How to install the arduino IDE and the UNO drivers". And those tutorials come with step by step instructions and pictures. That's exactly what a total beginner needs. So I stand with by my answer. Your comment however is short and lacks any form of explanation. Maybe you are the one that has some rethinking to do.