# how to change variable when a button connected to pin 2 is pressed

Tags: arduino-uno, serial, programming, c++

Hi i am writing a code where, i have to switch a variable called toggle from 0 to 1 to 0.... every time the button is pressed (the button is on a 2 pin). I am a little lost as I am new to arduino need some help. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Go [here](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/HomePage) --> Built-In Examples. Read the examples for Button, Debounce, and Digital Input Pullup. Digital Input Pullup is the best single one of those 3 I think, but read them all.

Those 3 are key.

Also, I wrote a buttonReader (debouncing) library [here](http://www.electricrcaircraftguy.com/2014/05/ercaguybuttonreader-library-for-arduino.html).

Sounds like you're a beginner, so check out Adafruit's tutorials [here](https://learn.adafruit.com/category/learn-arduino).

And lastly, I've compiled links to all my knowledge at the bottom of my article [here](http://www.electricrcaircraftguy.com/2014/01/the-power-of-arduino.html).

Comment: You might want to make your answer a little bit more substantive than simply including links to sites that may or may not exist by the time someone else looks at the question.

Answer (score 2):

What you need is to detect a *transition*. That is, either:

- It was closed and is now open.

Or:

- It was open and is now closed.

To do that you need to "remember" the previous state of the switch and detect a change, like this:

```
const byte switchPin = 8;
byte oldSwitchState = HIGH;  // assume switch open because of pull-up resistor
bool toggle;

void setup ()
  {
  pinMode (switchPin, INPUT_PULLUP);
  }  // end of setup

void loop ()
  {
  // see if switch is open or closed
  byte switchState = digitalRead (switchPin);

  // has it changed since last time?
  if (switchState != oldSwitchState)
    {
    oldSwitchState =  switchState;  // remember for next time 
    toggle = !toggle;   // toggle the variable
    delay (10);         // debounce
    }  // end of state change

  // other code here ...

  }  // end of loop
```

---

For more information see my post about [switches](http://www.gammon.com.au/switches).